# Is there a way to have a gradient match the actual height of a web page?

Tags: html, css

I am using a gradient that looks great on my page. If you resize the browser the gradient changes to match perfectly. But, if you scroll the page down to view the contents, the gradient begins to repeat itself, ignoring my background-repeat: no-repeat rule.

Is there a way to have the gradient match the height of a page when scrolling without repeating itself?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you talking about? gradient maps the whole height, there's nothing to repeat or no-repeat a gradient background....

Comment: Could you share your code to help people understand better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
}

body {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));

        /* Safari 5.1, Chrome 10+ */
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

        /* Firefox 3.6+ */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

        /* IE 10 */
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);

        /* Opera 11.10+ */
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
  }
```

I get solution from here: http://cssmatter.com/blog/full-page-gradient-background-css/

Please let me know if is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed my issue, but I used a picture(saved a gradient as a PNG file). I believe this will work on your gradient too. You might need to mess with the percents to get it exactly what you want!

```
html{
background-image: url("yourGradientpicture.here");
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

-Hoyt

Answer (score 0):

Manish, You can use css property for this instead of background-image

```
    #grad {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */
}
```

Source [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If gradient is fix for all your HTML page (assuming you are using CSS gradient) and you do not wish any having repetition, you could try this this approach:

http://jsbin.com/nisawaboyu/1/

Basically applies the gradient to the whole HTML page, the size of the gradient is linked with the content size.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
html{
background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#1e5799), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1e5799 0%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}

    </style>


</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```